# Android 2.0 application can run on other smart phones : Android

Tags: android, android-screen-support

For example, if we build an application for Android 2.0, will it work on

1. Droid Incredible
2. Droid Global
3. Droid Pro
4. Droid X
5. Tablet PCs like Samsung Galaxy Tablet (http://www.samsung.com/us/mobile/galaxy-tab )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes.

As long as the device meets the minSdkVersion you set in your AndroidManifest, the app can run on that device.  If you also set a target version, you need to make sure you only call methods that are available (via reflection) when using newer SDK features.

For the Galaxy Tab specifically, you should [check their site for details](http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/galaxyTab.do).

Comment: Can you give a small example that, how to set minSdkVersion, and what does it mean, if if set minSdkVersion as 1.5 and I want to run my application to all above(Which are declared in my question), then what processes I have to do.

Comment: In your AndroidManifest you can have something like this: <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4" />  That says that the app requires at least version 3 (Android 1.5) to run, but uses features from version 4 (Android 1.6).  Android 1.5 did not support multiple resolutions and that support was added in 1.6.  By setting these values this way, you can include higher resolution assets while still running on the previous version.  See here for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

Comment: Ok, one more confusion, if I set <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="4" /> and any method which introduced in API 4+, is it gives an error, if my app runs on API 3?

Comment: Using a method in 4+ in your code will compile fine but will result in a Force Close if run on an Android 1.5 device.  You can choose to either set your minSdkVersion higher or you can use reflection.  See more here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/04/backward-compatibility-for-android.html